# When to use a log scale?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I know about log scales, in general.

I know it's also used to make an exponential into a linear.  Like Richter 1, 2, 3, etc is really 10, 100, 1000.  So, it helps to compress the axis units.

Also, to preserve percentage growth in a graph.  eg: 1 to 2 has the same vertical jump as 100 to 200.    This prevents the significant 1 to 2 jump to be buried in a flatline on a chart scale of 0 to 200.

In the graph below, you have 3 variables relating to fund managers:  Age, Assets Under Management (AUM), and Performance.  Why is the AUM log scaled?

In general, 
[image]

How did you get 22,000 and 10 billion?  Can you explain your calculation?  The log(AUM) scale goes from 10 to 23.  On the AUM axis, 10 really means 10=log(AUM).  Based on the definition of log(), this means "the exponent for 10 to get AUM is 10.  That would make 10^10 = AUM.  Or 10,000,000,000 = AUM.  $10B for AUM on the low side.  On the high end of the scale, you have 23.  As in, the log(AUM) = 23.  "the exponent for 10 to get AUM is 23.  That would make 10^23 = AUM.  Or, AUM = 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.   What am I doing wrong??

Comment: For example, I use log-scale to see better what is going on with values very close to 0.

Comment: log scales work well when you have very small and very large numbers (this is often the case with quantites you see reported in decibels, such as signal-to-noise ratios).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the range is so large.  Presumably they are using natural logs, so AuM runs from 22,000 to 10 billion.  If a linear scale were used almost all managers would be compressed down into the bottom bin.  If you had 200 bins, the bottom one would be from 0 to 50M, which would cover all the data up to 18 on this chart.

Comment: How did you get 22,000 and 10 billion?  Can you explain your calculation?  The log(AUM) scale goes from 10 to 23.  On the AUM axis, 10 really means 10=log(AUM).  Based on the definition of log(), this means "the exponent for 10 to get AUM is 10.  That would make 10^10 = AUM.  Or 10,000,000,000 = AUM.  $10B for AUM on the low side.  On the high end of the scale, you have 23.  As in, the log(AUM) = 23.  "the exponent for 10 to get AUM is 23.  That would make 10^23 = AUM.  Or, AUM = 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.   What am I doing wrong??

Comment: I believe they are using natural logs, not base $10$.  $\exp(10)\approx 22000, \exp(23) \approx 10B$

Comment: Ok, let me try using ln() instead of log().  On the AUM axis, 10 really means 10=ln(AUM). Based on the definition of log(), this means "the exponent for e to get AUM is 10. That would make e^10 = AUM. Or 22,000 = AUM on the low side.  On the high end of the scale, you have 23. As in, the ln(AUM) = 23. "the exponent for e to get AUM is 23. That would make e^23 = AUM. Or, AUM = 9,744,803,446 or ~ $10B.  Yes, I got it.  Thanks!